# Setting a global map in Grails

Tags: caching, grails, web-applications, dictionary, grails-plugin

I am building a Grails web app, I created a map in BootStrap and placed it in servletContext in order to make it available to my application from anywhere. On average this map should hold about 1000 entries with String keys and Date value.

I was wondering if that can impact my application performance and there is a better place to keep this map ? I want this map to work as a caching mechanism. I wanna put a unique Key in it and a date, and be able to retrieve that date object from anywhere such as within a controller, or service class by passing the key. I was thinking of using a caching mechanism to do that but haven't find one that can do this form. I appreciate it if anyone can suggest any plugin for Grails that can achieve this.

P.S: Is it possible to do this with Cache Plugin : http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/docs/manual/guide/usage.html#annotations

Comment: it's better to put it into a service, like `MyCachingService`

Comment: can you please explain a bit and elaborate on your answer ?

Comment: I mean service could be a better place, rather than servletContext. easier to use, etc

Comment: So if I have it in a service, All I do is to initial the service at start up within bootstrap and it will be alive as long as the application is running ?

Comment: yes, it will be alive all time. also you can mark it as `implements InitializingBean`, so you don't need bootstrap at this case at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Service for this task. Service is a singleton, so it will be alive all the time. And it's much easier to access from other parts of app. To prepare data on application startup, you can `implements InitializingBean`.

Foe example:

```
class MyCacheService implements InitializingBean {

  Map cache

  void afterPropertiesSet() {
     cache = [
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        // .....
     ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the Map is not thread-safe, but since the service instance is a single, there shouldn't be any problem with different controllers trying to add or remove items to the Map cache, am I right ? P.S: Do I have to make this transaction=true or just leave it as it is ?

Comment: I need to make methods like addToCache and getFromCache, I can put them all after "void afterPropertiesSet()" ? Btw what is the use of this method ?

Comment: This is from Grails website : Services can be registered within a number of different scopes, but the default is application (or singleton) scope therefore your code needs to be thread-safe.

ref: http://grails.org/version/Services/2

Comment: Got the answer here, Burt B answered it well http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/About-singleton-service-class-td3835635.html

Comment: Sorry, it was just example how to use Service. Of course, you have to make it thread-safe, etc. `afterPropertiesSet()` is the method of `InitializingBean` interface (make sure that your class implements it), that will be called on bean initialization

Comment: I implemented that class and made it hard to inject it using Spring, I'm not sure why but when I started my app it keeps saying that it's null anytime I wanted to use it. The moment I removed it everything was fine, like injecting would work as expected.

Comment: you mean that app doesn't see your service? make sure that you've followed grails docs, put into correct dir, etc http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html

Answer (score 0):

About making the Map cache thread-safe, we can use ConcurrentReaderHashMap cache so that does mostly-concurrent reading, but exclusive writing. That way everyone can read it from the service but not everyone can write to it or modify it at the same time.

It is possible to use Synchronized block on the methods such as addToCache so that not two controllers can write at the same time, but for getFromCache we don't need that.

[Sample code for ConcurrentReaderHashMap](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/metaclass/ConcurrentReaderHashMap.html)